# Autocad custom attributes translate to svf and read by Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

the customer data can be either of dwg file level or object level(such as XRecord), is it possible that Viewer reads it like reading metadata from Revit? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract custom data using the approach described [in this sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-custom-data-viewer). As of now, the sample runs on Design Automation v2, we're migrating it to v3.